# Am I solving this capacitance equation correctly?

Tags: capacitance, low-pass, math, clock-speed

The following is a datasheet excerpt about satisfying the clock-signal requirements for a low pass filter

> When using the internal oscillator, the capacitance (COSC) from CLK to
> ground determines the oscillator frequency:
>
> $$ f_{osc} (kHz) = \frac{10^5}{3C_{osc} (pF)} $$
>
> The stray capacitance at CLK should be minimized be
> cause it will
> affect the internal oscillator frequency.

Now bear with me as I solve the equation out loud using a 330 pF capacitor:

$$
f_{osc} (kHz) = \frac{100000}{3 * 330 (pF)}
$$

$$
f_{osc} (kHz) = \frac{100000}{990 (pF)}
$$

$$
f_{osc} (kHz) = 101.01
$$

Did I do that right? How would I minimize stray capacitance?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100pF is large enough that any stray capacitance will be smaller than the capacitor's tolerance (and therefore negligible) unless you make the traces on your PCB excessively long (centimeters) or buy a very precise and expensive capacitor. Just keep the trace between the IC and the capacitor short and thin. That's all you need to do. Ideally, you'd use a small SMD capacitor and place it right at the CLK pin.

Keep in mind that RC oscillators generally aren't particularly accurate due to component tolerances. You should expect that the frequency may be off by 10% or so, and possibly more if you use a cheap capacitor. The datasheet of your IC should give typical frequency tolerances.

Your calculation seems to be correct.

Comment: Be sure to use a COG/NPO capacitor. These have a low temperature coefficient and a low voltage coefficient. Regular ceramics are very voltage dependent.